# Magento: How to add attribute to product price?

Tags: magento-1.7

I created a new attribute (delivery) for my Magento shop and I'd like to show this attribute right after the product price on the product page. How can I do that?

I tried to add echo `$_product->getdelivery()` at view.phtml but my attribute showed up in the next line and not next to the price.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your code to catalog/product/price.phtml
else you can add css to .price-box but this would change in many places as price-box is used in many places

Better to add a class in price.phtml to price-box. Give the new class float left and add your div next to it. :)

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you know what part of price.phtml has to be changed to add my code for the product page? I can´t find the matching code.

Comment: <div class="price-box"> 
add another class to this
give that class css property float left
after that add your delivery in a div which is float left